# How do I change "new Line" in IntelliJ IDEA when auto format code

Tags: intellij-idea

Every time when I want to reformat my code in IntelliJ IDEA it starts a new line when the text reaches this white line. But I don't want it there I want it further right. How do I change it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your margin width

[image]

My version: IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.1 (Ultimate Edition).

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ is just doing what you asked it to,
what the prefs specify.

In Mac PyCharm, click CMD-, (comma) prefs
-> Editor -> Code Style -> Hard wrap at: N columns

Either adjust N to your favorite value,
or untick the "wrap on typing" checkbox.

Other JetBrains products will
offer similar dialogs.